# Backups fail to NFS share using Deja Dup

Tags: mount, backup, nfs, deja-dup

I've been trying to set up backups using the Ubuntu Backups app (Deja Dup).  The destination is an Asustor NAS running the NFS sharing service.

I can mount the share just fine using the command line (sudo mount) and read/write files to it using Nautilis, but when I try to enter the network path into Deja Dup it returns this error:

> Permission denied: Perhaps this host is disallowed or a privileged
> port is needed

What am I doing wrong?  Is there some syntax I'm missing in specifying the network path?

The path I'm specifying is:

```
nfs://192.168.3.5/Asus-Backups/
```

I'm happy to use another service if that's easier.  The Asustor will do FTP, SSH, SMB/CIFS, WEBDAV, etc.  NFS is the one I have most experience with, though.

Edit:I'm having the same problem with two clients.  One using Ubuntu 22.04, the other Mint 21 XFCE.

Comment: You are running Deja Dup as `root` (`UID 0`). For security reasons, NFS remaps UID 0 requests to user `nobody`. `ssh`, if you're willing to do the reading, although Samba can work, too

Comment: Hmm. Is Deja Dup set to run as root by default?  It doesn't ask for a password as other root GUI apps do (synaptic, updates, etc).

Comment: Well, I took Walt's advice and went with SSH and it's working now.  Still confused as to why NFS is so hard to make work. Seems like NFS shouldn't be mentioned in the info box if it's so unlikely to work.